# React Js : Repeatable layout

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a layout, which renders Cards in a specific layout like first row 3 small cards, next row - 2 Medium cards, 3rd row has 1 large and small card

```
let layoutOrder = ['SSS', 'MM', 'LS'];


// code below works fine
let layoutOrder = ['SSS', 'MM', 'LS'];
    let containerList = layoutOrder.map((rowCapacity, idx) =>
        ( <
            rowLayout key = {
                idx.toString()
            }
            rank = {
                idx.toString()
            }
            cardType = {
                rowCapacity
            }
            json = {
                this.getItems(rowCapacity)
            }
            />
        ));
getItems(rowCapacity) {
    let begin;
    let end;
    if (rowCapacity === 'SSS') {
        rowCapacity = 3;
    } else {
        rowCapacity = 2;
    }
    begin = this.counter;
    this.counter += rowCapacity;
    end = this.counter;

    var groupingData = _.extend(this.json);
    let some = groupingData.slice(begin, end);
    return some;
}
```

My render method :
    render () {

```
    return (
        <section className="cards-layout">
            {this.containerList()}
        </section>
            );
 }
```

Now, the fun part: the number of cards can be from 1 to 100+. From the code above , you may find that, I am adding cards to a rowLayout component based on the given layout.

So the code above would stop when it has iterated through layoutOrder.

**Need / Ask **: What I am looking for is : the layout should repeat until there are cards in the Json object.

So right now, if my json has 27 cards, the code above will stop at 7th iteration and thats it. I want the layout should repeat until the number 27th.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Quite hard to understand your code, why are you put this empty for() in third line? ) any way is it render function of component? If it is, try to not update any model from it, do all state calculation before render... or in other life cycle methods

Comment: My bad. Edited. removed the empty for

Comment: `let baseLayout = ['3', '2', '2'];
     for (var i=0; i < this.json.length; i++) {
         // render cards, based on above base layout until it iterates
     }`   baseLayout [0]  =3 , meaning it will have 3 cards

Comment: Batter to operate something like real object in your state, if you wanna output some cards somewhere add something like cardsDesk = {smallCards:[{name:smallCard1},{name2: smallCard2}, bigCards:[...]} then you can iterate through this subarrays and it will be explicitly to read, sorry i still didn't get whole idea) but rendered something based on numbers still possible ... you can use for loop in react renderalso